# Integrate: $\int{6\over x^3-1}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I need to solve this problem: $$\int{6\over x^3-1}dx$$

Here is what I have so far: $$\int{6\over x^3-1}dx = 6*\int{1\over(x-1)(x^2+x+1)}dx$$

Next, $${1\over(x-1)(x^2+x+1)} = {A\over x-1} + {Bx+C\over x^2+x+1}$$

Continued, $${1\over3}*\int{1\over x-1}dx - {1\over 3}*\int{x+2\over x^2+x+1}dx$$

First off, is that last step correct (after equating and stuff)? Also, what would the next step be?

I know that $${1\over3}*\int{1\over x-1}dx = {ln\lvert x-1\rvert\over3}$$ At least I hope it does. I just can't figure out $$ -{1\over 3}*\int{x+2\over x^2+x+1}dx$$ There aren't any trig identities, u-sub obviously would not work here, I'm not sure about integration by parts, I can't decompose it since the bottom is not factorable. I'm guessing I have to write it differently by splitting it somehow, I just can't see how though. Any help? At least a hint?

Thank you!

Comment: The `\begin{align}` · · · `\end{align}` environment and `\cdot` operator seem relevant here. You can read about them [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint. $$\frac{x + 2}{x^2 + x + 1} = \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{2x + 1}{x^2 + x + 1} + \frac{1.5}{(x + \frac{1}{2})^2 + \frac{3}{4}}$$

Comment: Ok, thank you. I have: $$\int{2x+1\over x^2+x+1}dx={ln\lvert x^2+x+1\rvert\over 2}$$ Is that correct for that part? I'm still working on the next part, but I'm having a bit of trouble.

Comment: yes, the next part you should have something with $$arctan \ or \ (tan^-1)$$

Comment: @valer Hmmm, I'm not seeing how I would get something with $tan^-1$ This is what it looks like $${3\over 2}*\int{1\over (x+{1\over 2}^2)+{3\over 4}}dx$$ Do I have to somehow get it into the correct form for integration? So I can use the basic integration formula to get tan?

Comment: Substitute $$ u=x+\frac{1}{2} \ and \ write \frac{3}{4}=(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2})^2$$ @DevHeavy

Comment: @valer Ok, so $$u = x + {1\over 2}$$   $$du=dx$$ and $${3\over 2}*\int{1\over u^2 + {\sqrt 3\over 2}^2}du$$ Is that what I'm supposed to get? Still not completely sure what is happening here.

Comment: yes the last one is to the power of 2 soo you should get the $$ \frac{1}{a} \cdot arctan(\frac{u}{a}) $$, $$ \ where \ in \ our \ case \ a=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} $$ @DevHeavy

Comment: @valer To bring this together I should have: $${1\over {\sqrt 3\over 2}} * {arctan({x+{1\over 2}\over {\sqrt 3\over 2})}}$$ Correct?

Comment: Yes that is correct @DevHeavy

Comment: Ok, finally, here's my final result: $${ln(x^2+x+1)\over 2}+{{2\over \sqrt 3}*arctan({{x+{1\over 2}}\over {\sqrt 3\over 2}})} + {ln(x-1)\over 3} + C$$ @valer would you check that this is correct really quickly? Thank you for your help. Any mistakes? is it completly wrong?

Comment: @DevHeavy https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5B6%2F(x%5E3-1),x%5D

Comment: @MathLover ah, so mostly right, just a few negative signs off.